# Rails nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, associations, activeresource

I'm trying to get my head around nested associations in Rails using ActiveResource.
My example is as follows:
What I have is an airport with many runways.

My show action in airports controller contains:
    @airport = Airport.find(params[:id])

When I call http://localhost/airports/2.xml I get that piece of XML:

```
<airport>
  <code>DUS</code>
  <created-at type="datetime">2009-02-12T09:39:22Z</created-at>
  <id type="integer">2</id>
  <name>Duesseldorf</name>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2009-02-12T09:39:22Z</updated-at>
</airport>
```

Now, I changed the action to

```
@airport = Airport.find(params[:id], :include => :runways)
```

How can I achieve that above loading above URL is giving me something like:

```
<airport>
  <code>FRA</code>
  <created-at type="datetime">2009-02-12T09:39:22Z</created-at>
  <id type="integer">2</id>
  <name>Frankfurt</name>
  <updated-at type="datetime">2009-02-12T09:39:22Z</updated-at>

  <runways>
    <runway>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>bumpy runway</name>
    </runway>
  </runways>

</airport>
```

And on top of that: If I have a client with

```
class Airport < ActiveResource::Base
  ..
end
```

and

```
class Runway < ActiveResource::Base
  ..
end
```

How can I get it to automatically load associations like:

```
a = Airport.find(1)
puts a.runways.length
=> 1
```

And (last but not least): Is there a way to store data from the client like:

```
a = Airport.find(1)
a.runways << Runway.find(1)
a.save
```

Maybe I'm really too blind, but I'm stuck...
Any idea is warmly welcome.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Did you ever figure out the a.runways << Runway.find(1) part of this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:include` option for the finder specifies that it should eagerly fetch the related items from the database.  The `:include` option for `to_xml` specifies that it should be included in the XML rendering.

If the canonical XML representation includes the related objects, you can override the `to_xml` method to make your life a little simpler:

```
class Airport
  def to_xml(options={})
    super(options.merge(:include => :runways))
  end
end
```

and then since `render` will call `to_xml` if you don't, your controller code can simply be

```
format.xml { render :xml => @airport }
```

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it myself finally.
Wasn't aware to put the include into the render statememt:

```
def show
  @airport = Airport.find(params[:id], :include => :runways)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @airport.to_xml(:include => :runways) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This isn't documented in many places. I've had to search for a long time.